# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'products'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm a newbie to Django. I'm following a tutorial where I should create a model class called products.

This is what I've included in my models.py document inside my APP called Products:

```
class Products (models.Model):
title = models.TextField()
description = models.TextField()
price = models.TextField()
```

Then I added the APP to INSTALLED APPS in my setting.py document:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #third party

    #own
    'products',
```

However, when I tried to run the following command on my terminal I get an error:

```
(env) dcorreavi@dcorreavi src % python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()
File "manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/dcorreavi/Dev/trydjano/python-virtual-environments/env/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/dcorreavi/Dev/trydjano/python-virtual-environments/env/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Users/dcorreavi/Dev/trydjano/python-virtual-environments/env/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Users/dcorreavi/Dev/trydjano/python-virtual-environments/env/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/Users/dcorreavi/Dev/trydjano/python-virtual-environments/env/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", 
line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'products'
```

Comment: Try 'Products' with upper case

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'products.apps.ProductsConfig',
]
```

instead of only `products`

Answer (score 0):

'products.apps.ProductsConfig' added to installed app section in settings

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the following packages

```
pip install django-extensions
pip install ipython
```

go to `settings.py` -> `INSTALLED_APPS` and add `django_extensions` app

run via `./manage.py shell_plus`

`django-extensions` automatically imports the models and classes we need (for example, `ProductCategory`, `Product` and others, which you will learn about later)

`ipython` - for the convenience of using the terminal, it allows you to enter the `clear`, `cd`, `pwd` commands without opening a new terminal

Answer (score 0):

comment out`'products',` from *settings.py.*

run this command first from your source folder (where manage.py is):

```
python manage.py startapp products
```

then go back and add `'products',` in *settings.py*